# What is Form Layouts?

Tags: channel, layouts

Seems a a beginner question, but what it is the Form Layouts inside the Manage Channels?
[image: form layouts]

After creating a form layouts, what is its use? How to use it ??
I didn't remenber at all what it is a form layouts....

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Form layouts is where you can setup the input form and fields for entering data via the Create or Edit entry pages.

You can save a layout for specific users per channel so that a given user will see the entry form that you have saved to a layout. In this way, you can reorder or hide fields as needed.

For example, say you have a user that you don't want to have input certain fields.  You can create a layout for that user so that the fields you don't want them to see are hidden.

Note that you can also customize the available tabs like date, options, etc and even drag and drop the tab fields between other tabs.  In this way, you could make a layout that has the date fields and entry status on a single sheet and completely do away with tabs if you wanted to.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot,  i stayed a long time away from EE, and i didn't remenber at all about form layouts. Because of your explanation, I understood what it it 

Comment: Well explained!